# Restoring deleted packages on Azure ADO feed when the Recycle Bin does not work

Tags: azure-artifacts

We have a configured Upstream Source in our ADO. So, builds are adding different revisions of the packages as they run. In my case the problematic package is:

[image]

Although its name to my understanding is not important. This package has numerous revisions:

[image]

Some revisions show up as deleted, some not. How can I restore the deleted packages?

I see Microsoft documentation and numerous articles on the web on how to do that using the **Recycle Bin**. In my case the Recycle Bin is empty. What should I do next if this is possible at all?

The only thing that I can think of is to delete the package with all its revisions. This should delete the history of versions. Will that work? Is there any better way here?

Answer (score 0):

If you need publish a package version that already exists on one of your upstream sources, you must disable that upstream source, publish your package, and then re-enable the upstream source. See [Override packages from upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#override-packages-from-upstream-sources).

But once you publish a particular version of a package to a feed, that version number is permanently reserved. You cannot upload a newer revision package with that same version number, or delete it and upload a new package with the same version number. Please refer to [Immutability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/artifacts-key-concepts?view=azure-devops#immutability) for details. Thus, it’s suggest to re-fetch it from the upstream feed with a new version. If you are unable to publish a new version, please try to create a new feed to publish the same version of the package that you want.